# C++ DirectX has D8016 error due to version of C++ not being used

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx

I created a DirectX project in visual studio which worked until I changed the version of C++ being used from C++14 to C++20. It gave me this error when I attempted to build
cl : command line  error D8016: '/ZW' and '/std:c++20' command-line options are incompatible
so I changed the settings to use 14 again though it still gave the same error. I know it's not a problem with my code as I didn't change it between this working on not working.

I've tried mess around with the cl settings but that seems to do nothing. When I change the version to C++17 it still has the same problem thinking it's C++20. When I try using latest it will say latest has is incompatible. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3gIH.png)

I've also tried creating a new project to which I would copy the code over however when I try doing the new projects have a completely different bug where VS will close when they are built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/ZW` switch is specifically for the C++/CX language extensions used for Windows Runtime APIs typically for [UWP applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide). As these language extensions have been deprecated in favor of the more modern C++/WinRT language projections the C++/CX extensions are not compatible with a number of modern C++ Standards conformance features.

You have three basic choices here:

1. Continue to use the [C++/CX language extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/visual-c-language-reference-c-cx) but stick with the default language setting of C++14. *You likely need to rebuild all if you are getting the error after switching it back*.

> This also means if you try to make use of `/permissive-` that you'll need to add `/Zc:twoPhase-`.

2. If you want to target the UWP app platform with C++17 or C++20, switch to using the [C++/WinRT language projections](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/intro-to-using-cpp-with-winrt) instead. You can install the [C++/WinRT VSIX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264) to get new templates or you can make use of the C++/WinRT templates from [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates).
3. If you want a DirectX template for classic Win32 desktop programming which uses neither C++/CX nor C++/WinRT language projections, you can find them on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates). *Visual Studio has no built-in "DirectX templates" for classic Win32 desktop development.*

Comment: I took your advice and experimented with WinRT however I get the same problem as I did when trying to create another directx project where VS closes when the build has finished and either reopens or stays closed. Do you know what might be causing that?